# curl is not working in my ubuntu vps

Tags: php, curl, ini

I am using ubnutu server in atlantic vps. I have installed lamp stack and all the required configuration for php. I have installed curl and it is also enabled. in php.ini `allow_url_fopen = On;` ; but it still not working.

Comment: How will we help you without looking at your code? Why do you think it is not working? Logs?

Comment: Hi, I have already got the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the php cURL extension by logging into the command line of your vps and entering the following command...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

You then need to restart the server using the command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you are using php-fpm you will need to restart php5-fpm instead using the command

```
sudo service php5-ftp restart
```

cURL is the better option anyway as it isn't affected by security configurations in PHP such as forbidden fopen of remote URI's etc.